# Moving iPhone slows down SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I am making a SpriteKit game (space shooter) with the latest Xcode and iOS versions on an iPhone 6 plus. The weird thing is that if I start playing and proceed to "shake" the phone or in any way move it around, the FPS immediately start dropping into the 20's. My game doesn't in any way make use of the accelerometer or gyro which makes this even more strange. Does anybody know how to fully turn off the gyro/accelerometer or otherwise avoid this issue? This happens even if not touching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody runs into this, I noticed that restarting the iPhone corrected the issue. The issue seems to arise after doing several "build and runs non stop for a couple of hours.

Comment: you probably had some other app running in the background that did not handle the accelerator correctly